# get dropdown value to textfield

Tags: flutter

I am new in Flutter. I Cannot get the value from dropdown list to a textfield

```
                                             Container(
                                            height: 18,
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            height: 68,
                                            width: 80,
                                            child: TextField(
                                              maxLength: 4,
                                              autofocus: true,
                                              inputFormatters: [
                                                UpperCaseTextFormatter(),
                                              ],
                                              controller: TextEditingController()..text = _meals_state,
                                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                                icon: Icon(Icons.text_fields),
                                                hintText: 'meals_state',
                                                labelText: 'Meals State: ',
                                                border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                                              ),
                                              onChanged: (String? value) {
                                                if (value != null) {
                                                  _meals_state = value;
                                                }
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          // END TEXT FIELD                     
                    

                    DropdownButton(
                                              menuMaxHeight: 600,
                                              hint: Text("Select State"),
                                              value: _mealState,
                                              items: getStatesList(),
                                              onChanged: (String? value) {
                                                setState(() {
                                                 _meal_state = _mealState,
                                                      }));
                                                });
                                              }),
```

const List stateInitials = [
"AL",
"AR",
"AZ",
"CA",
"CO",
"CT",
"DC",
"DE",
"FL",
"GA",
"IA",
"ID",
"IL",
"IN",
"KS",
"KY",
"LA",
"MA",
"MD",
"ME",
"MI",
"MN",
"MO",
"MS",
"MT",
"NC",
"NE",
"NH",
"NJ",
"NM",
"NV",
"NY",
"OH",
"OK",
"OR",
"PA",
"RI",
"SC",
"SD",
"TN",
"TX",
"UT",
"VA",
"VT",
"WA",
"WI",
"WV",
"WY",
];

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

just declare the textController, then use it like,

```
final mealController = TextEditingController(); // initialize like this
TextField(controller: mealController) // declare like this
DropdownButton( onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() =>mealController.text = value); // use like this, maybe u don't need setState here, try it if u want
});
```

Now u r good to go. one suggestion, do something about code's structure while posting code.